# What am I missing here? Basic Bit Operation

Tags: bit-strings

Consider the bit strings  $A=001100$ and $B=010101$  then $A\vee B`= ? $ ($B`=$bitwise NOT)

First I wrote $B`$ and get,

$$B`= 101010$$

then I took first "$0$" of $A$ and "$1$" of $B`$ then get (1),

$$A\vee B`= (001100)\vee(101010) = (101110)$$

But this is accepted wrong.
What am I missing? 
Can't we negate $B$ in bit operation like this?

This was a multiple choice question and answers were like these

A-)001000
B-)011101
C-)101110
D-)010001

Comment: It depends on what ` is supposed to mean.  If it means bitwise NOT, then you're correct.  If it means something else, you may not be.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Yes it means bitwise NOT.

Comment: Seems correct to me, at least assuming $A\vee B' = A\vee (B')$ and not $(A\vee B)'$

Comment: Yes, they are written as seperate. Otherwise we must use De Morgan law. I ask this because this was an exam question and this answer did not accepted. Thanks for checking.

Comment: maybe it has something to do with priority of the operators.

Comment: Thanks for checking, I've also added choices of the question if you want to look.